# How to Convert SQL server to Oracle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, migration

I have a SQL server database (Tables, Views, SP...). I need to convert this database to Oracle 10g. How can I do it?

Comment: Please take a look at: [Migrating a Microsoft SQL Server Database to Oracle Database 11g](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/mssqlserver/migrate_microsoft_sqlserver_otn.htm)

Answer (score 5):

Transferring the data will be easy; SQL Server integration services can do that, or Oracle's SQL Developer.

However, views and stored procedures are different between Oracle and SQL Server.  SQL Server uses T-SQL, Oracle uses PL/SQL.  These are not very compatible and I don't know a tool can automatically convert between the two.  If your database relies on specific T-SQL features, you will need a developer to do the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Get the [jTDS jdbc driver from sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/1.3.1/).

Add it to [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/sqldeveloper).

Tools > Migration > Migrate

[image]

Create a migration repository in your new Oracle database.

Create a new migration project.

Point it to your SQL Server database.

Convert it - mind the data types.

Migrate the data:

1. online row-by-row inserts over JDBC. Fine for SMALL/test boxes.
2. offline - use micrsosoft's unload utility to pull the sql server down to flat files. SQL Developer will create SQL*Loader scripts to put them over into Oracle.
3. If you have GoldenGate licensed, use that to move the data over and to synch changes from one system to the other in case you need to keep both up and going.

Start looking at the migrated T-SQL procs and functions. SQL Developer will leave comments for code blocks it wasn't able to translate...but you will need to TEST and VERIFY every single translation. Customers can see upwards to 80-90% translation rates for their T-SQL, but it could be as low as 50%...it just depends on the nature of your code.

[The entire process is described here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/sqlserver-095136.html)

I wrote a [white paper](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/migrating-to-oracle-database-wp-3610526.pdf), with Sybase ASE as the example source platform, here. The process is identical for SQL Server. It has step-by-step guidance with screenshots.

If you have an Oracle account manager, reach out for help. We have specialists that deal exclusively with migrations such as yours. They have lots of practical advice and can recommend 3rd party partners if you lack the expertise.

Answer (score 0):

sql developer can help. You can download it here , it is free. http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/sql/index.html

Comment: How can sql developer help in this context? Can the tool automate things?

Answer (score 0):

There is step by step documentation including videos on how to migrate SQL Server to Oracle DB. You find it here:
[Migrating from Microsoft SQL Server to Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/sqlserver-095136.html)

Or you can use a tool to do the job for you like [Ispirer - Migrate Microsoft SQL Server to Oracle](http://www.ispirer.com/products/sql-server-to-oracle-migration)

Answer (score -1):

You basicaly setup an Oracle Server, once its ready you migrate your tables using a software made for that. I guess this script can do the job:
[m2o](http://sourceforge.net/projects/m2o/)