# Move Sql server 2005 to Oracle?

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle, database-migration

I want to move my SQL Server 2005 database to Oracle.  How can I do that?  What are the step I want to follow?  Are there any tools for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694133/how-to-convert-sql-server-to-oracle

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE : Sorry for the wrong information. Find something useful [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS-SQL-Server/Q_24374479.html) and a tool [here](http://dbconvert.com/convert-oracle-to-mssql-pro.php).