# Generate Oracle SQL scripts from SQLSERVER Database

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2005, database-migration

I have a Microsoft SQL Server database(tables, relationships and data).
But now I want an exact same copy of this database in Oracle.
I was thinking there may be some sort of a tool or converter that could generate Oracle sql scripts that I could run to create and populate my new Oracle database.
Is this kind of thing possible?
And how can I achieve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move Sql server 2005 to Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763693/move-sql-server-2005-to-oracle)

Comment: @Conrad - and the question you reference is a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694133/how-to-convert-sql-server-to-oracle which also points out that stored procedures can be a problem as no automatic tool will be able to convert those from T-SQL to PL/SQL (aomthing I missed in my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a DB modelling tool which can reverse engineer your SQL Server database and then generate a script to recreate it in Oracle.

[DB Designer Fork](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbdesigner-fork/) can do this for you and is Open Source.