# will functionalities of stored procedure remains same aftermigration of data from ms sqlserver to oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

what are steps needed to be carried out for migrating the data from ms sqlserver to oracle11g.
Will all the views and stored procedures works well after migration?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Convert SQL server to Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694133/how-to-convert-sql-server-to-oracle)

Comment: There's quite a few tools out there that do this.  I did it once with Oracle SQL Developer.  It's not a seamless transition with that tool; you might look at some of the paid tools out there that do the same thing.

Comment: can u suggest which paid tool do good for me?

Comment: Views shouldn't be a problem. But considering that SQL Server uses a language called T-SQL (Transact-SQL) for its procedures and etc, and Oracle uses PL/SQL, and that the ways these languages interact with their respective databases are significantly different, it means that every procedure will need to be rewritten. This is not a simple process. Best of luck.

Comment: No idea. Razorsql is the best advertised at the moment. It's unlikely your stored procedures will be foolproof afterwards, because the languages are different.

Comment: It seems like i want to start from scratch,but any way thank u @DylanB

Comment: @BobJarvis our translator can handle most of the work from t-sql to plsql. What is a challenge is when a direct 1:1 translation doesn't make sense - when to get the full power of Oracle, you need to change the way your code works fundamentally.

Comment: @DylanB SQL Developer is a paid tool - when you pay for Oracle Database, that includes SQL Developer. It's an important distinction because it includes SUPPORT. Which can be utilized for doing migrations.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: I wrote this answer for the original question, which was 'migration of data from ms sqlserver to oracle
'. It's generally the same answer for the updated questions as I do cover the translation process*

Get the [jTDS jdbc driver from sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/1.3.1/).

Add it to [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/sqldeveloper).

Tools > Migration > Migrate

[image]

Create a migration repository in your new Oracle database.

Create a new migration project.

Point it to your SQL Server database.

Convert it - mind the data types.

Migrate the data:

1. online row-by-row inserts over JDBC. Fine for SMALL/test boxes.
2. offline - use micrsosoft's unload utility to pull the sql server down to flat files. SQL Developer will create SQL*Loader scripts to put them over into Oracle.
3. If you have GoldenGate licensed, use that to move the data over and to synch changes from one system to the other in case you need to keep both up and going.

Start looking at the migrated T-SQL procs and functions. SQL Developer will leave comments for code blocks it wasn't able to translate...but you will need to TEST and VERIFY every single translation. Customers can see upwards to 80-90% translation rates for their T-SQL, but it could be as low as 50%...it just depends on the nature of your code.

[The entire process is described here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/sqlserver-095136.html)

I wrote a [white paper](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/migrating-to-oracle-database-wp-3610526.pdf), with Sybase ASE as the example source platform, here. The process is identical for SQL Server. It has step-by-step guidance with screenshots.

If you have an Oracle account manager, reach out for help. We have specialists that deal exclusively with migrations such as yours. They have lots of practical advice and can recommend 3rd party partners if you lack the expertise.

Comment: Will the views and stored procedures work OK? Well, you could have tens of thousands of those. And they'll generally be just queries. Our translator handles these scenarios very well. We'll update the data model and your code appropriately if we need to change the name of a table or column so that it propagates down into your code objects. But you need to TEST..TEST..TEST.

Comment: Many, many, many customers have done successful migrations from SQL Server to Oracle using SQL Developer.

Comment: Okay, so......  I appreciate that you both work for Oracle and are open about it. But having used the particular tool you're promoting, there are some drawbacks. Datatypes don't operate exactly the same across the two platforms, among other problems that can't actually be addressed. I dispute, though, that someone unmarked this question from being the duplicate it is.  A simple Google query finds three separate answers to this question, and while this is the most recent I really wish you'd go resubmit this answer to the other two (or edit them) and leave this one marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Of course they don't - but you are able to override the data types we default to and use the ones you prefer. Is there a way to move answers @DylanB ?

Comment: Not MOVE, but proposing edits to old answers and / or adding additional answers to the ones that are already there is the way the system is designed to work. That way the answer becomes well-ranked reference material.\

Comment: Ok, so I posted my answer to the 'original' is it now proper etiquette for me to remove my answer here, @DylanB?

Comment: Not really.  The whole question should be flagged a duplicate and closed.